# Remove both thunderbird and evolution email cinnamon ubuntu

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, cinnamon

I have installed the cinnamon desktop environment using `sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment` on my Ubuntu machine. I noticed there was a lot of applications pre-installed that I was never going to use so I tried removing them from the terminal. I started with the games and then got to the email clients (thunderbird and evolution). This sounded easy

```
sudo apt-get remove thunderbird* evolution*
```

But then when I checked to see if the email applications were removed thunderbird was still installed and evolution was gone. How do I remove both email clients?

Comment: Be careful with '*' in `apt` commands, and you didn't mention the release, but `evolution-data-server` is not part of the MUA (mail user agent program), but part of the GNOME stack and is needed likely needed by Cinnamon too.  Your release details are first thing likely useful.  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=evolution; evolution MUA you'll notice is from 'universe' as optional, `evolution-data-server` is from main as needed by GNOME & other GTK stacks for calendar functions)  Check out you've not created problems for yourself in the future...

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 and newer, '*' and similar wildcards don't work anymore with apt.

Comment: I tried this and it worked: `sudo apt-get purge evolution thunderbird`

Answer (score 0):

Try purging both packages with a command like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge evolution thunderbird
```